# How to create a website link without the leading http://

Tags: hyperlink, adobe-indesign

I'm creating a merge document. My only remaining problem is with websites. InDesign doesn't seem to want to create a link unless "http://" is included with the address, but the world knows that http:// is the beginning of the address, and since http:// is pretty ugly, I'd like to create linked text without the http://.

Comment: You could do the world a favor and use https://

Comment: Use a grep style where http:// is set to fontSize 0,1pt and paper as fillcolor.

Comment: Seems it doesn't matter where one goes on the Internet, there's always a Michael Schumacher trolling the boards..........

Comment: Thank you, Loic. That's a tactic that I use often in Word and, for some reason, just hadn't thought about it for InDesign. Not elegant, but if it increases aesthetics, I'm all for it!

Comment: @Loic you should post that as an answer